# Getting multiple HTTP resources concurrently in Angular2

Tags: http, typescript, angular

I can handle a single observable result from `http.get` with following code:

```
http.get('/customers/1')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(customer => this.customer = customer);
```

Now I have a list of resource IDs like `var list:number[] = [1, 4, 7];` that I want to be able to send request for all resources and assign the all resolved items to my array like `customers => this.customers = customers`.

Comment: Check [forkJoin](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md)

Comment: thanks @EricMartinez ,  this solved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Rx.Observable.forkJoin](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md) can do this.

First import Obserable & forkJoin:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
```

or import all

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Now join all observables with `forkJoin`:

```
// a set of customer IDs was given to retrieve
var ids:number[] = [1, 4, 7];

// map them into a array of observables and forkJoin
Observable.forkJoin(
    ids.map(
        i => this.http.get('/customers/' + i)
            .map(res => res.json())
    ))
    .subscribe(customers => this.customers = customers);
```

Comment: Great answer! There's a detailed explanation available here too http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angular-2-http-observables